# Unable to run/find JSHint

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jshint

Brand new to Grunt trying to put together a configuration file and having some difficulties. I'm trying to run JSHint, and the file is unable to be found.

Directory set up is

```
./htdocs/[js, css, sass, images, html files]
./build/[]
.node_modules/[grunt,grunt-contrib-compass/watch/htmlmin/uglify, jshint, matchdep]
./Gruntfile.js, package.json
```

Currently JSHint is installed globally using `npm install jshint -g`
Next running `jshint -v` returns `jshint v2.6.3`

So that's telling me it's installed plus it's in my node_modules directory

My Gruntfile.js reads as

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
var globalConfig = {
    src: 'htdocs',
    dest: 'build'
};
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    globalConfig: globalConfig,
    // CONFIG ===================================/
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: ['**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass']
        },
        scripts: {
            files: ['**/*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                spawn: false
            }
        }
    },
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= globalConfig.src  %>/sass',
            cssDir:  '<%= globalConfig.dest  %>/css'
        },
        dev: {}
    }
});
// DEPENDENT PLUGINS =========================/
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
// TASKS =====================================/
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch','jshint']);
```

}

package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "Demo",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Optimized template test",
 "main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
 "author": "user",
 "license": "ISC",
 "devDependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.5",
  "grunt-contrib-compass": "^1.0.1",
  "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
  "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.8.0",
  "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
  "matchdep": "^0.3.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "grunt": "^0.4.5"
},
"keywords": [
  "DemoOne"
]
}
```

Now every time I run `grunt` I'm getting `Error: Task "jshint" not found` I've tried putting `"jshint": "^2.6.3"` inside the "devDependencies" array but that didn't seem to help either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying a **task** cannot be found, not the jshint executable.

You need to define the Grunt task like in the [documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint):

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    all: ['Gruntfile.js', 'lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
  }
});
```

EDIT: And of course you need to have [`grunt-contrib-jshint`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint) in your package.json as well.

Comment: Is that version still viable as the Build is noted as Failing? I supposed the confusion came in as there are so many variables and instances of JSHint.

Comment: If you check it on [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/branches), you can see he is working on it. The latest in [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-jshint) should be okay.

Comment: Also, the source of the build failure is a JSHint warning about an unused variable.. :D Which has now been fixed in the other branch (latest build).